# window.location.replace(); is not redirecting the page on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to redirect the page when the button is clicked, but when i click the button it only refreshes the page and i stay at the same page

i have also tried this :

```
window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
```

Current jquery:

```
<script>
        $(".ola").click(function () {
            var bl = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(bl);
            window.location.replace("menu.aspx?Pay=" + bl);

        });
    </script>
```

button:

```
divNaoPago.InnerHtml += "<td><Button type=\"submit\" id=\"" + BL4 + "\" class=\"ola\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">Pay</Button></td>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your code like so:

```js
  $(".ola").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var bl = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(bl);
    window.location.replace("menu.aspx?Pay=" + bl);
  });
```

Comment: why did this work? I have already used window.replace like i showed and it worked fine why isnt it working now and why is that `(event)` and `event.preventDefault();`, im sorry i am new to jquery

Comment: @MiguelAraujo https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp, Here you van find a fine explanation.

Comment: You have a button of type `submit` and the default action of this button is to _post_ to the endpoint specified in your form. If you want that js takes the control you need to prevent the default action that come first.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.replace("menu.aspx?Pay=" + bl);

instead of this try this one window.location.href("menu.aspx?Pay=" + bl);

Comment: i tried to put `window.location.href("menu.aspx?Pay=" + bl);` and it is still the same output